# Use Dojo's Publish Subscribe Model

Tags: dojo

We are working on a portal environment. On one of our page we have two portlets. When some action happens on one portlet, we have to minimize the other portlet and viceversa.
So we feel that this is a suitable situation where we can use Dojo's publish/subscribe model. But I'm a bit confused if I need to use different topics [One when some action happens on Portlet A, and the second topic when some action occurs on PortletB] or one topic [something like minimize]. Can someone please guide me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really up to you, and depends on your needs.

Topics are free-form texts, so you can arrange it in any text format you like.

My own experiences have been to treat a topic as an "event".  Therefore, one topic, one event.

My experience has also been that it is tremendous beneficial to implement "commands" in the same system as events -- so you have a universal command/event system.

Events (therefore topics) do not have to correspond to your portlets.  For instance, one portlet can have multiple events (if they make sense), or one event can be shared by multiple portlets (for shared functionalities or for cross-portlet communcations).

Parameters and data can be passed with the event (i.e. topic) as arguments.

Now, a good trick I've learnt is to have "sub-topics" -- i.e. topics that are prefixed with an parent topic, when things want to subscribe to a particular instance of event.

Example: Assume we have an event called "/portlets/showhide" which is published by any portlet when it is shown or hidden, together with the id of the portlet and a boolean variable indicating whether it is shown or hidden.

Now, assume that a portlet will also publish topics called "/portlets/showhide/{id}" (with true/false argument) and "/portlets/showhide/{id}/show" (no arguments) when shown, together with the generic "/portlets/showhide" topic (event).

Now assume some handler object is really only interested when the "xyz" portlet is hidden.  It doesn't have to subscribe to "/portlets/showhide" and listen to all those events of other portlets that it is not interested in.  It can simply subscribe to "/portlets/showhide/xyz/hide".  When number of subscriptions increase in a large system, this kind of optimizations can come in quite handy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one topic in which pass additional parameters. Something like this:

```
// PortletA
dojo.publish("onPortletAction", [{sender: "PortletA"}]);

// PortletB
dojo.publish("onPortletAction", [{sender: "PortletB"}]);
....

dojo.subscribe("onPortletAction", dojo.hitch(window, window.processAction));

window.processAction = function(data) {
    if (data.sender == "PortletA"){
             //to do something
        }
        if (data.sender == "PortletB") {
             //to do something
        }
}
```